# Nest ng-repeat in a <select> dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'd like to create a nested `ng-repeat` that allows me to include all questions in all chapters of a survey JSON in a dropdown `<select>` menu. What's the "right way" to do this? I could see creating an array just for this particular use case, but would rather not do that.

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="chapter.jumpId">
    <span ng-repeat="chap in survey.chapters">
        <option ng-repeat="question in chap.questions" value="question.verbose">
            {{ question.id }}
        </option>
    </span>
</select>
```

Comment: you pretty much got it, you could use ng-options too.

Comment: yep change span to select and you  are good to go

Comment: you can check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: Thanks, @AlpeshPrajapati - You've set me on the right track (`ngOptions` is useful in general). My problem still stands, though, with the opting to use that tool, unfortunately: I now still need to get all questions for all chapters such that something like the following would work: `<select class="form-control" ng-model="chapter.jumpID" ng-options="question.id for question in chapter.questions for chapter in survey.chapters">`

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati if you are able to elaborate on that in an answer I would be happy to mark this question as answered, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Html:**

```
<select ng-repeat="chap in survey.chapters">
    <option ng-repeat="question in chap.questions" value="question.verbose">
        {{ question.id }}
    </option>
</select>

-----

<select>
    <option ng-repeat="sOption in sOptions" value="sOption.verbose">
        {{ sOption.id }}
    </option>
</select>
```

**Js:**

```
$scope.survey = {
        "chapters" : [
            {
                "questions" : [
                    {
                        "verbose" : "que1_verbose1",
                        "id": "que1_1"
                    },
                    {
                        "verbose" : "que1_verbose2",
                        "id": "que1_2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "questions" : [
                    {
                        "verbose" : "que2_verbose1",
                        "id": "que2_1"
                    },
                    {
                        "verbose" : "que2_verbose2",
                        "id": "que2_2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

$scope.sOptions = [];

angular.forEach($scope.survey.chapters, function(chapter) {
   angular.forEach(chapter.questions, function(question) {
      $scope.sOptions.push(question);
   });  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9bc06fdv/27/

Comment: Unfortunately, this creates 2 separate select lists - whereas I need both lists' contents to be condensed within a single `<select>` tag.

Comment: Hi Darshan - I was trying to avoid using an array that also sat in the scope. I wrote in my question: "I could see creating an array just for this particular use case, but would rather not do that." I'll leave this open for a little longer - if I don't get any answers I'll give you the answer, under the premise that this is indeed the only way to accomplish my goal.

Comment: As of now, I have not any other solution. I did research on that but everyone follow similar kind of method.